# Sending email to array of recipients on php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am looking to send email to multiple recipients but i am not able to do so.. here is my code.

```
using print_r() statement
Array
(
    [selectedvalue] => Array
        (
            [0] => muralidego@gmail.com
            [1] => muralidego@yahoo.com
            [2] => ezhil@emirates.net.ae
        )
}
```

and i want to use this emails in mail($mailDO->toEmail)

```
mail($mailDO->toEmail, $mailDO->subject, $mailDO->message, $headers);
```

kindly help me out...thanks.

Comment: `implode(',', $emails)` or a `for`-loop

Comment: use `foreach($urarray["selectedvalue"] as $key=>$val){ mail($val, $mailDO->subject, $mailDO->message, $headers);  }`

Comment: @u_mulder, Then all recipients would be able to see others email too. Will cause a **privacy** uproar ;)

Comment: Yes, and that's why I mentioned a `for`-loop as another option

Comment: @u_mulder, You edited that just now. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach`

```
foreach($yourarr['selectedvalue'] as $email)
{
 mail($email, $mailDO->subject, $mailDO->message, $headers); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a foreach loop like [Shankar has posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22805688/2471423), or you can add them to your headers as another `cc`.

```
$headers .= 'Cc: muralidego@yahoo.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: ezhil@emirates.net.ae' . "\r\n";
```

Or if you don't want them to know, then you can do:

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: muralidego@yahoo.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: ezhil@emirates.net.ae' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: If this is corrent, can you upvote + mark as correct then please? :) @muralidego

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine all email addressed into single string to be used with mail().

```
mail(implode(',',$yourarr['selectedvalue']),$mailDO->subject, $mailDO->message, $headers);
```

Based on the tags you imply you are using MySQL. In that case you can already handle this as part of the query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT email SEPARATOR ",") FROM your_table WHERE somerule=1;
```